# IBM RTC - Precondition Plug-in for prohibit system out println

Tags: eclipse, rtc

I have got requirement to create plug-in that can be attached as pre-condition in 'deliver client'.

When I deliver my java code to stream, if there is any `system.out.println` call, deliver should fail.

Suppose, if I create the plug-in, how to attach that plugin in pre-condition UI.

Could you please guide me what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

To put in place your precondition, you can follow "[Team process preconditions for Rational Team Concert source control](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_scm_eclipse_process_preconditions.html&scope=null)".

You can see example of existing preconditions in "[Source control process recipes for Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/library/article/1075)", but in your case, this is a custom one.

See "[Rational Team Concert - Creating Custom Operation Advisors](https://jazz.net/library/article/495)": you will be able to create a new plugin.

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/2.0.0.2/custom-operation-advisors/images/image002.jpg]

You might need to work with the RTC admin in order to install that plugin on the RTC server.